# Printing command line argument into new Linux tex file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

first time asking a question on stack overflow. I'm a student working on a small Linux todo list app where a user can create new files using a command like this:

```
./todo add "hello world"
```

...and the result should be a new text file in a todo list with the text "hello world" (or whatever is within the " ").

What I have so far: my bash script add.sh creates a new file, adds it to the todo list and renames all the items in that list to create a numbered list like this:

1.txt
2.txt
3.txt

Here's my code for add.sh:

```
echo $2 >> newFile.txt. #creates a new file
mv newFile.txt ~/todoApp/usrMenu/todo #moves file to todo list
cd ~/todoApp/usrMenu/add && ./name.sh #renumbers all files in the todo list
```

But here's my question:
how do I get the $2 argument in the command line ("hello world") to be a text in my new file?

Right now, when I cat the new file, it's blank. What I want is for the new file to read "hello world."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is `./todo` related to `add.sh`?

Comment: ./todo is a bash script that you can use to call any other function/script in the directory ~/todoApp.

Comment: Can you post `./todo`? It sounds like the problem is in that script and not in `add.sh`

Comment: Yes, and thanks! That part of my code is really basic. It's just an if-else tree, where `if [ $1 == "add" ] then ./usrMenu/add/add.sh #calls add.sh` and the rest of the tree calls other bash scripts.

Comment: Just pass the argument to the script: `./usrMenu/add/add.sh "$2"`

Comment: Remember to always quote variables unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: In `add.sh` it should be `$1`, not `$2`

Comment: This is a good reminder that no code is too basic to post. A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you verify by copy-pasting from your post into a new directory is a great way to ensure that the question captures everything.

Comment: @thatotherguy absolutely - you probably fixed a problem that would have gotten in the way of most of my other scripts that ./todo could call with a simple "$@". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `./todo` script:

```
if [ $1 == "add" ]
then
  ./usrMenu/add/add.sh #calls add.sh
fi
```

You do not pass the parameters from `./todo` to `add.sh`, so `$2` in `add.sh` will be empty and different from `$2` in `todo`. To pass all parameters, you can use `"$@"`:

```
if [ "$1" == "add" ]
then
  ./usrMenu/add/add.sh "$@" #calls add.sh and forwards all parameters
fi
```

Or alternatively, only pass the parameter you care about, which will then become `"$1"` (NOT "$2") in the script:

```
./usrMenu/add/add.sh "$2" # Let "$2" in this script become "$1" in add.sh
```